# C++ parsing sub nodes of xml

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

Well here I am again working on this open source game, anyway I made this parser for an xml file however I am unsure how to parse the vocation's children nodes, here is the code and the xml for the function, I want to be able to loop through its children, I assuming I need to create another for loop, however I am not quite sure how I should would reference vocation's child nodes, I am not concerned with their attributes atm.

```
bool Game::loadCreatureAdditionalAttributes()
{
    pugi::xml_document data;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = data.load_file("data/XML/attributes.xml");
    if (!result) {
        printXMLError("Error - Game::loadCreatureAdditionalAttributes", "data/XML/attributes.xml", result);
        return false;
    }
    bool attributesEnabled = false;
    for (auto attributeNode : data.child("attributes").children()) {
        if (strcasecmp(attributeNode.name(), "additionalAttributes") == 0) {
            if (attributeNode.attribute("enabled").as_bool()) {
                if (strcasecmp(attributeNode.name(), "vocation") == 0) {
                    pugi::xml_attribute vocation = attributeNode.attribute("id");
                    uint32_t aNode;
                    pugi::xml_attribute attr = attributeNode.attribute(attributeNode.name());
                    if (attr) {
                        aNode = pugi::cast<uint32_t>(attr.value());
                    }
                    else {
                        aNode = 0;
                    }
                    CreatureAttributes[pugi::cast<uint32_t>(vocation.value())][attributeNode.name()] = aNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And now the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attributes>
    <additionalAttributes enabled = "0" />
    <vocation id = "1">
        <attribute stamina = "1" />
        <attribute strength = "1" />
        <attribute intelligence = "1" />
        <attribute dexterity = "1" />
        <attribute wisdom = "1" />
        <attribute luck = "1" />
        <attribute critical = "1" />
        <attribute block = "1" />
        <attribute experienceGain = "1" />
        <attribute power = "1" />
        <attribute precision = "1" />
    </vocation>
    <vocation id = "2">
        <attribute stamina = "1" />
        <attribute strength = "1" />
        <attribute intelligence = "1" />
        <attribute dexterity = "1" />
        <attribute wisdom = "1" />
        <attribute luck = "1" />
        <attribute critical = "1" />
        <attribute block = "1" />
        <attribute experienceGain = "1" />
        <attribute power = "1" />
        <attribute precision = "1" />
    </vocation>
</attributes>
```

Edit 1:

Haven't tested this just yet, but I thought I'd show an update based somewhat on the answer given.

```
bool Game::loadCreatureAdditionalAttributes()
{
    pugi::xml_document data;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = data.load_file("data/XML/attributes.xml");
    if (!result) {
        printXMLError("Error - Game::loadCreatureAdditionalAttributes", "data/XML/attributes.xml", result);
        return false;
    }

    auto attr = data.child("attributes").child("additionalAttributes");
    bool attributesEnabled = attr.attribute("enabled").as_bool();

    if (attributesEnabled) {
        for (auto vocation : data.child("attributes").children("vocation")) {
            uint32_t id = pugi::cast<uint32_t>(vocation.attribute("id").value());
            for (auto attribute : vocation.children("attribute")) {
                for (auto& a : attribute.attributes()) {
                    CreatureAttributes[id][a.name()] = pugi::cast<uint32_t>(a.value());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Not exactly sure if child to child is legal... but just throwing it out there lol

Edit 2:

Still haven't tested it yet, just updating it in case it doesn't work as expected.

```
bool Game::loadCreatureAdditionalAttributes()
{
    pugi::xml_document data;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = data.load_file("data/XML/attributes.xml");
    if (!result) {
        printXMLError("Error - Game::loadCreatureAdditionalAttributes", "data/XML/attributes.xml", result);
        return false;
    }

    auto attr = data.child("attributes").child("additionalAttributes");
    if (attr) {

        bool attributesEnabled = attr.attribute("enabled").as_bool();

        if (attributesEnabled) {
            for (auto vocation : data.child("attributes").children("vocation")) {
                uint32_t id = pugi::cast<uint32_t>(vocation.attribute("id").value());
                for (auto attribute : vocation.children("attribute")) {
                    for (auto& a : attribute.attributes()) {
                        CreatureAttributes[id][a.name()] = pugi::cast<uint32_t>(a.value());
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just wanted to give an update for those having similar issues, the code works great!

```
vocation id = 1 attributes = stamina value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = strength value = 45
vocation id = 1 attributes = intelligence value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = dexterity value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = wisdom value = 63
vocation id = 1 attributes = luck value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = critical value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = block value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = experienceGain value = 1
vocation id = 1 attributes = power value = 81
vocation id = 1 attributes = precision value = 1
vocation id = 2 attributes = stamina value = 100
vocation id = 2 attributes = strength value = 1
vocation id = 2 attributes = intelligence value = 20
vocation id = 2 attributes = farfenugen value = 1
vocation id = 2 attributes = stackoverflow value = 1000
```

Of course I changed the code a bit to make it work with other code I am working on, but the example code in `Edit 2` will work fine with an xml file similar in structure.

Comment: I guess I could just run some tests and see what the output is :p

Comment: Didn't have to run any tests :) I think I have the solution tho will post it when I compile and test it.

Comment: That's not a very easy format to parse when you have different attribute names for each `<attribute>` nodes *attributes*.

Comment: Personally I would probably make those `<attribute>` nodes actual *attributes* of the `<vocation>` node like `<vocation id="1" stamina="1" strength="1"... etc>` Or else make each attribute its own tag `<stamina>1</stamina>`.

Comment: Well that didn't work out as expected and to make it work i would have to edit the accompanying SDK which is not something I know how to do although I could just overload the existing function but again I am still a beginner at c++ :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like `pugixml` a lot it makes parsing very easy. However your `XML` format is kind of tricky, I would consider storing your `<attributes>` differently.

Currently you can iterate through the *vocations* and the *attributes* like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PUGIXML_HEADER_ONLY
#include "pugixml.hpp"

auto xml = R"(
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attributes>
    <additionalAttributes enabled = "0" />
    <vocation id = "1">
        <attribute stamina = "1" />
        <attribute strength = "1" />
        <attribute intelligence = "1" />
    </vocation>
    <vocation id = "2">
        <attribute stamina = "1" />
        <attribute strength = "1" />
        <attribute intelligence = "1" />
    </vocation>
</attributes>
)";

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;

    doc.load(xml);

    for(auto vocation: doc.child("attributes").children("vocation"))
    {
        std::cout << "vocation id:" << vocation.attribute("id").as_string() << '\n';

        for(auto attribute: vocation.children("attribute"))
        {
            for(auto& a: attribute.attributes())
            {
                std::cout << "    attribute: " << a.name() << '\n';
                std::cout << "             : " << a.value() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would probably organize my `XML` more like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PUGIXML_HEADER_ONLY
#include "pugixml.hpp"

auto xml = R"(
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attributes>
    <additionalAttributes enabled = "0" />
    <vocation id = "1">
        <stamina>1</stamina>
        <strength>1</strength>
        <intelligence>1</intelligence>
    </vocation>
    <vocation id = "2">
        <stamina>1</stamina>
        <strength>1</strength>
        <intelligence>1</intelligence>
    </vocation>
</attributes>
)";

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;

    doc.load(xml);

    for(auto vocation: doc.child("attributes").children("vocation"))
    {
        std::cout << "vocation id:" << vocation.attribute("id").as_string() << '\n';
        std::cout << "           : stamina = " << vocation.child("stamina").text().as_string() << '\n';
        std::cout << "           : strength = " << vocation.child("strength").text().as_string() << '\n';
        std::cout << "           : intelligence = " << vocation.child("intelligence").text().as_string() << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you made it look soo easy and I have a better idea of how to construct the code for something else later on thanks again, you rock!